# Separate thread to launch Unity on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I created an Unity3d project.
I created a separate iOS project and I copied the Unity libraries and classes to the new one.
I succeeded to lunch the project and to add other UIViewControllers in the project.

My problem is that UnityController is working in the main thread and I don't know how to create another thread so the main thread won't be frozen when Unity is.

Any suggestions?

This is my AppDelegate code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navVC;

    self.unityController = [[UnityAppController alloc] init];
    [self.unityController application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and on my ViewController when I press the button to change to unity I call showUnityWindow in my AppDelegate

```
- (UIWindow *)unityWindow {
    return UnityGetMainWindow();
}
- (void)showUnityWindow{
    [self.unityWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Do you know about DispatchQueue?

Comment: Yes I know and I worked with it before but with unity in my code I don't know how to use it . If I put it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to init unity the app crash

Comment: Not sure if it's advisable (I haven't used Unity before), but can you possibly wrap the two unity lines in your app delegate in a DispatchQueue.main.async call? this way Unity works on the main thread but still lets you manage the rest of the app when Unity freezes

Comment: Actually that's what I thought , but when I wrapped it the app crashed

Comment: Yes from this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/180243/threading-in-unity.html looks like Unity won't let you run it in any other thread...but I believe you should be able to run it on the main thread asynchronously :P

Comment: hhh yes I believe that too but I didn't find a solution . Every time unity freezes all my buttons and lists freeze too :/